# How to remove stored SharePoint credentials in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015, credentials, sharepoint-online

While creating a SharePoint **(SharePoint online hosted)** app in Visual Studio 2015, I used my organization-issued **personal** account. While signing-in I accidentally checked the *Remember me* box.

And now, for another project, I have to log-in again using different credentials, which has **administrator** privileges. But, the sign-in page never shows up now.
I tried clearing internet explorer cache, repairing Visual Studio, reinstalling/updating SharePoint plugin etc., but nothing worked. It automatically logs me in using my personal account.
I tried finding keys in Windows Credential Store in Control Panel, but was unable.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We had a very similar problem as such you were not able to connect to Team Foundation Server with your own credentials.

To solve this problem

- Open the Credential Manager in Control Panel
- Edit the Generic Credentials to be your own account
- Close and open Visual Studio 2015
- Reconnect to TFS
- Enter your credentials in prompt poping up

**Note**: Do not forgot to uncheck the option "**Remember my credentials**" to force to ask credentials for every TFS connections.

Now, you will be able to connect to Visual Studio 2015 with your account from now on.

Comment: There are a lot of credentials; how to find the correct one?